# Who changes the status on a pull request?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

My colleague and myself has this question for who should change the status on the pull request from "Active" to "Resolved". Andre is the one writing the code and Leighton is reviewing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reviewer should decide when a pull request is resolved